# Django Logging - Unable to set propagate to False

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, python-logging, django-logging

What I'm experiencing is getting duplicate entries in my logs. I've looked around, and it seems that I have to set `'propagate': False` in my loggers configuration which I have already done. However when I printout the `logger.propagate` it returns `True`. I even tried to manually set `logger.propagate = False` but it still returns `True` and I'm receiving duplicate entries in my logs.

What might be the cause of problem?

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.propagate = False
```

```
class PostsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Getting both twice
        logger.error('Something went wrong!')  
        logger.error(logger.propagate)  # Returns True
        queryset = ...
        return queryset
```

```py
 LOGGING = { 
      "version": 1,
      "disable_existing_loggers": False,
      "formatters": {
          "simple": {
              "format": "{levelname} {message}",
              "style": "{",
          }   
      },  
      "handlers": {
          "console": {
              "level": "DEBUG",
              "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
              "formatter": "simple",
          },  
      },  
      "loggers": {
          "app": {
              "level": "DEBUG",
              "handlers": ["console"],
              'propagate': False,
  
          }   
      },  
  }
```

I also tried setting `"disable_existing_loggers": True`, but it has no effects.

Answer (score 1):

As for getting duplicate log entries, I found out that the cause is `get_queryset` method being called twice in order to display the forms as my `BrowsableAPI` is enabled.

However I still have not Idea why `logger.propagate` returns `True`.

Comment: Most likely you are setting the propagate on a different logger. Have you checked that the value of `__name__` is actually identical to the name of your logger?